# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable in live object detection

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I get this error while I'm working on a GitHub project on live object detection.

```
File "C:\Users\pankaj\Documents\models\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 759, in visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array
    box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code:

```
# Create a display string (and color) for every box location, group any boxes
# that correspond to the same location.
box_to_display_str_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
box_to_color_map = collections.defaultdict(str)
box_to_instance_masks_map = {}
box_to_instance_boundaries_map = {}
box_to_keypoints_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
box_to_track_ids_map = {}
if not max_boxes_to_draw:
    max_boxes_to_draw = boxes.shape[0]
for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
    if scores is None or scores[i] > min_score_thresh:
        box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())  # **This is the line error is referencing to**
    if instance_masks is not None:
        box_to_instance_masks_map[box] = instance_masks[i]
    if instance_boundaries is not None:
        box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box] = instance_boundaries[i]
    if keypoints is not None:
        box_to_keypoints_map[box].extend(keypoints[i])
    if track_ids is not None:
        box_to_track_ids_map[box] = track_ids[i]
    if scores is None:
        box_to_color_map[box] = groundtruth_box_visualization_color
    else:
        display_str = ''
```

How do I resolve this and what does it actually mean?

Comment: welcome to python ! can you show us how the `boxes` variable is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

`boxes[i].tolist()` is returning a single floating point value, but `tuple()` requires its argument to be iterable, and single floats aren't iterable.

Given the function name `tolist()`, it seems like the function ought to return single items as a list.

A quick fix might be to force the result to be a list, like so:

```
box = tuple([boxes[i].tolist()])
```

But this seems like a bad solution, because if `tolist()` ever did return an actual list, this would force it to be a list-of-list, which probably isn't what you want.

It seems like the real solution is to modify `tolist()` to always return a list, even if it's just one item.